# how can I verify if variable is passed to template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the situation:

**application.html.erb**

```
<html>
<title><%= yield(:title) + ' | ' if :title.present? %> Website Name</title>
....
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
```

So I want to print a specific page title only if such a title is provided via `provide`.

But it seems that all methods tried return the same thing either the variable `:title` is provided or not

```
>> defined? :title
=> "expression"
>> defined? :anything
=> "expression"
>> :title.present?
=> true
>> :anything.present?
=> true
>> :title.nil?
=> false
>> :anything.nil?
=> false
```

Comment: This is the way you test if there is a content for variable <%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Test" %>, :something.present? actually tests if the symbol is not nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the most convenient way is to add this to your application_helper.rb file:

```
  def full_title(page_title)
  full_title = "Your Site Title"
    if page_title.empty?
      full_title
    else
      "#{full_title} | #{page_title}"
    end    
  end
```

Then on each page view you can put at the top something like:

```
<%= provide(:title, "My About Section") %>
```

And then in your application/layout view in the head section you can call it via:

```
<title><%=full_title(yield(:title))%></title>
```

This leaves the method "full_title" to check if anything was provided instead of logic in your application layout view.